# SSRS Execution Time - Interactive sorting impacts execution time when using report variable

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

This question is an extension to a question already answered - SSRS Execution Time on Two Page Report - [SSRS: Showing the correct execution time on a two page report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483402/ssrs-showing-the-correct-execution-time-on-a-two-page-report)

Using a report variable solves the issue of anchoring the execution time when viewing a report with multiple pages.

Unfortunately this does not anchor the execution time when interactive sorting is enabled. My requirement at this point is to anchor the execution time of the report to only the initial run time.

Apologies if I am misusing the term anchor, I just want the execution time to hold once the report has initially run.

Thanks!