# PowerBI: report execution time indicator

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, powerbi

I have a problem similar to the one within this topic:
[SSRS: Showing the correct execution time on a two page report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483402/ssrs-showing-the-correct-execution-time-on-a-two-page-report). Well the problem is practically the same but the BI tool is different it's not in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder but in PowerBI. I have searched for something similar, some kind of execution time indicator that will show how long report was generated. I know that PowerBI is different from Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder but both are BI tools that allow to create reports from many kinds of sources (SQL queries for example).

Perhaps someone found a solution for my problem during his/hers work and could post a solution for my problem? I would be much obliged.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/06/09/power-bi-diagnostics-trace-logs-and-query-execution-times-again/)?

Comment: I'm currently reading this. It's somewhat hard for me to understand all of this but it's certainly useful so it may be one of the answer for my problem for sure.